# How to store regex date pattern in JSON

Tags: java, json, regex

My code requires me to store regex string in JSON. this is working fine for most of the patterns but lands in trouble when date pattern with '/' is used

i tried escaping with a '\'

`(\\d{1,2}\/\\d{1,2}\/\\d{1,2})` this seems to be working fine as JSONLint does give any error

however the challenge is when i am trying to parse the JSON string in a JAVA program it gives error as it further requires '\' and '/' to be escaped. I have tried multiple options but not able to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proposed regex escapes a backslash too many: Have a look at: https://regex101.com/r/xBFeZG/1

It's only the \ that needs to be escaped in java regexes, so transforming what I believe you want to that would be:

```
 (\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,4})
```

However, why not simply use a standard date format (like: dd/MM/yyyy -> see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and do something like:

```
LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an expression like

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}
```

then exporting it as JSON will produce something like this

```
{ "regex": "\\d{1,2}\/\\d{1,2}\/\\d{1,4}" }
```

with every "\" being escaped as "\\".

To parse correctly in Java, you really just have to "un-escape" the escaped backslashes, in other words, remove the leading backslash. Something like this should work:

```
String regex = jsonRegex.replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");
```

**EDIT**: Forward slashes don't actually need to be escaped, although escaping them doesn't hurt. So, the expression will most probably be emitted in JSON like

```
\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,4}
```

Comment: i am using SimpleDateFormat for converting to date format, however the need for regex is to identify the date fields from random text

Comment: @Vivek Great! Your question though was about parsing the regex from the JSON, not how to pass dates from component to component. So, I give you an answer for your specific question and you go accept the other guy's irrelevant answer!! Oo

Comment: the question was about when I am trying to parse the json which contains a date pattern it was not working for me...

My apologies if it did not come out clearly. appreciate your answer though. unfortunatlely could select only one answer and that is what worked exactly for me